# Add new partial to Rails 7 generate scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, scaffold

Rails 7 removed table generation and I want it back. Reading the guide on generators did not help me so I dug into the source and found a way.  I always preferred my table in a separate partial _table.html.erb.

So I created a `config/initializers/gen_ext.rb`

```
require "rails/generators"
require "rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator"
Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator.send(:undef_method, :available_views)
Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator.send(:define_method, :available_views, ->(){
    %w(index edit show new _form _table)
})
Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator.superclass.source_paths << '/app/lib/templates/erb/scaffold'
```

It adds `_table` to the hard coded `available_views` in the `Erb::Generators::ScaffoldGenerator`.  I found I had to update the `source_paths` to get it to take.  I was happy.

Then according to the guide I should be able to add the other templates in that folder as well. I create `/app/lib/templates/erb/scaffold/index.html.erb` and it doesn't work.  I debugged and found the following lines in my `config/initializers/gen_ext.rb` are what break it.

```
require "rails/generators"
require "rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator"
```

I read the source and I can't figure out why.  So close to what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Najd.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I've been using more often the `render partial: name, collection: @models` which will create as many partials as the number of items in your collection.

It's performance is good, IMO, and I usually add the TR/TDs to that partial and call it from within the table.

something like:

```html
<table>
  <head>
    <th>Column Header</th>
  </head>
  <tbody>
    <%= render partial: table_line, collection: @models %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With kind regards,
Rogerio